# Soteri brute forcing tag edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Exhibit A: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/149427

Rejected by Schroeder because he thought it was not about MD5 specifically (I thought it was and approved, but I was also doubting; I can see it either way).

Exhibit B: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/149436

Attempt to introduce the same MD5 tag that they tried to introduce earlier. Currently pending. I happened to recognize the post title and knew to reject it, but Overmind didn't (of course, because he didn't see the previous one) and hit approve.

Exhibit C: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/149435

The "key" tag is not for product keys. Soteri doesn't read the tag description before attempting to add it.

Exhibit D: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/149377

Same problem as C. Adding to the problem is Overmind apparently also not reading the tag description and reviewing as approve.

Exhibit E: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/149428

In the 20 seconds it took me to write a reject reason, the post's author, someone with 1 karma and no other network accounts (presumably new to the site), accepted the suggestion. I rolled it back because the question has as much to do with nmap as it has to do with the fact that this happened on planet earth. I said as much in a comment below the post, hoping either or both would see it, deleting the comment after they had both been online two hours later since I didn't want to clutter the post. (Somehow Soteri still got the edit-approved bonus, not sure why that's not reverted on rollback same as with removed votes. And for me it didn't count towards the review queue badge because "it was already approved" when I tried to review it, but whatever.)

Exhibit F: https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/224906/revisions

See my edit message.

---

They don't seem to be reading the reject reason - which is understandable, as you don't get a notification for rejected suggestions - and there is no PM system through which I could contact them.

A ban is also not what I'm looking for, since [some of the edits are useful](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/149273). Probably with some editing experience it also gets *more* useful and accurate.

What do?

Comment: Possibly a mod message explaining that if an edit was rejected, trying to get the same edit through is a bad idea? I honestly don't know